# Microsoft TFS Build Automation - ASPNETCOMPILER error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, msbuild

I'm trying to get the build automation going for our TFS solution. The solution contains multiple class libraries, and one web site (not a web project). Everything seems to build fine, except for the web site. I'm getting the following error:

ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The target directory is not empty, and does not appear to contain a previously compiled application. Please delete it manually, or choose a different target.

I'm building the solution for Release and Mixed Platforms. The bin folder for the web site is not checked into TFS, and it's not read-only. Many of the class libraries get compiled into the web bin folder, I don't know if that is what's causing the problem. I am a beginner at this, so I might not have configured something right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by installing Web Deployment Projects and creating a web deployment project for my web site. So that's what was missing. :) I only wish the error message could have been more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

also for others: you sometimes get this if your .Net Temp Files folder has files in it. You can try deleting them from %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem and to resolve it I unchecked the read-only file attribute of the folder containing the solution. I only get this error when running msbuild. When I opened the solution in VS2010 I didn't get this compile error.